# Can I replace -Inf values with 0 in my matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, heatmap

I'd like to consult one thing. I have a simple example matrix, let's say:

```
mx <- rbind(c(1,0,3,418),c(0,1,12,677),c(284,54,1,1),c(312,1,0,1))
mx
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    3  418
[2,]    0    1   12  677
[3,]  284   54    1    1
[4,]  312    1    0    1
```

Now I'd like to visualise this data, so I created a heatmap:

[image]

Unfortunately the values e.g. `mx[2,3]` (12) and `mx[3,2]` (54) are barely visible. The thing this I'd like to underscore them in my plot. So I came up with the idea of simple log transformation which won't affect and distort the data:

```
mx_log <- log2(mx)
mx_log
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 0.000000     -Inf 1.584963 8.707359
[2,]     -Inf 0.000000 3.584963 9.403012
[3,] 8.149747 5.754888 0.000000 0.000000
[4,] 8.285402 0.000000     -Inf 0.000000
```

Looks promising but of course this transformation results with `-Inf` for zeros and `heatmap.2()` won't work, so I tought to replace `-Inf` with zeros and the create new plot:

```
mx_log[mx_log == -Inf] <- 0
mx_log
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 0.000000 0.000000 1.584963 8.707359
[2,] 0.000000 0.000000 3.584963 9.403012
[3,] 8.149747 5.754888 0.000000 0.000000
[4,] 8.285402 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

[image]

Now it looks better but I'm worried of data manipulation because after log tranformation original values of 1 are now 0 and zeros of original dataset -> -Inf -> 0 (my manipulation). So my question is, can I do such thing to improve the visualisation of my dataset?

Comment: I'm not sure it is the right answer but a common thing that I observed in several publications is to add +1  to the value being log-transformed (`log2(value+1)`). Like that the minimal `log2(value+1)` will be 0 (if value equal to 0), avoiding the conflict with -Inf values.

Comment: How about using `tanh()` or `2/pi*atan()`, which provides bounds between -1 and 1 and is monotonically increasing

Comment: You can use `mx[] <- ecdf(mx)(mx)` to get the cumulative distribution of your values, which can be used for colors.